# optimizing my dataset for regression analysis over time

Tags: merge, dataset, spss

I have a question in regards to optimizing my dataset. I have a dataset of around 5000 individuals that i follow over time (with around 50 variables). However i have duplicate cases... for example: ID:1 Year:1 ID:1 Year:2 ID:1 Year 2. Therefore to make sure that no double years are present i used casestovar to not lose data.

However no that i have used casestovar with index i have many variables. I have to change those variables so that when i revert the dataset back with varstocases i no long have these double years!

How do I do this?

(extra info: i did casestovars so that i did not lose the information as the duplicate cases are only partially the same (some variables are some are not)).

Kind regards,

Instinct

Comment: you need to clarify what you want to do with the differences in data repeated in different years. For example, do you want to select one instence? do you want to average or sum them?

Comment: Hi eli-k,This depends on each individual variable. Most need to be summed others just need to be present as a new variable next to the existing ones.

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you, you should explain your question more clearly and add to your post a bit of sample data demonstrating what you have and what you need to do.